# problems to handle numbering extencion the number fixed with twilio studio

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-click-to-call

I created an integration with my anura telephone operator with twilio but I have the following query since it is a telephone operator .how do I make an outgoing call to an extension of this telephone operator the extensions? to which I want to communicate it are with the 104 of origin +51 1 XXXXXXX(THE XXXX ARE THE FIXED NUMBER)

[image: IMAGE TWILIO STUDIO WIDGHETS]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Say/Play widget to send DTMF (touchstone of the extension) once the call is answered by the main number IVR.

[Play Digits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/sayplay#play-digits-configuration)

Comment: place as you mention it with say but the call is not transferred and hangs up when the digits are pressed

Comment: Does it require a delay before you enter the extension? You can include a delay using a `w` between digits, each `w` is worth half a second of delay.

Comment: I already put it but in the same way it does not recognize it

Comment: Record the call and listen to what is occurring to determine next steps.

Comment: rings when the 3 digits are dialed after they ring the call ends –

Comment: So the far end is hanging up? Does it behave the that way when you dial from your mobile phone and enter the extension?